# SharePoint 2013 Mega Menu (MMS driven) - How to replicate the same mega menu for all the web applications and all the site collections

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, megamenu

SharePoint 2013 Mega Menu (MMS driven) - How to replicate the same mega menu for all the web applications and all the site collections? The mega menu is only available for 1 site collection. Is there a powershell way to propagate mega menu from source to all the site collections among all the web applications (about 500 sites)

Answer (score 0):

If the mega menu has been applied on a master page, so you can apply the same master page to all site collections within a web application using the below PowerShell Script

```
$site= Get-SPSite HTTP://webappURL #rootsiteURL
$WebApp = $Site.WebApplication
foreach($spSite in $WebApp.Sites)
{
    foreach ($web in $spSite.AllWebs)
    {
            $web.MasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl +  "/_catalogs/masterpage/YourMasterPage.master";
            $web.CustomMasterUrl = $site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/YourMasterPage.master";
            $web.Update();
    }
}
```

> Repeat the above steps for each web application on your farm

> **Note:** I would suggest creating a new web application with multiple site collections on a test environment to test the above script before applying it on the production

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont recall using masterpage for the mega menu. Is that where you have to change the child stuff in the masterpage?